# NLog how to use class member variable in log?

Tags: nlog

I am writing a program and I use NLog in it. I have several classes and in all of them I have the property

```
public string DeviceName { get; set; }
```

I want the logger to put this in front of my log message, so if for instance I have two classes

```
class A 
{
    public DeviceName {get;set;} = "HMP20"
    public void methodOne() 
    {
        logger.Info("Something");
    }
}

class B 
{
    public DeviceName {get;set;} = "HMP30"
    public void methodOne() 
    {
        logger.Info("Something");
    }
}
```

then the output in the log file should be

```
HMP20: Something
HMP30: Something
```

How does one achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The fast solution is to use the logger-name as device-name:

```
  public class A
  {
    public string DeviceName {get => logger.Name; set => logger = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger(value); }
    private NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
  }

  public class B
  {
    public string DeviceName {get => logger.Name; set => logger = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger(value); }
    private NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
  }
```

Then you can use the following layout-renderer: `${logger:shortname=true}`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I realise that I made a bad example. I updated it so that it gives you a more clear view of the thing that I want. Is your code still work with this example as well?

Comment: As you can see the DeviceName is not and in most cases will not have the same value as the class name.

Comment: There is a pending PR the allows one to inject a runtime property into the logger. https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/2496 (Similar to ForContext in Serilog) But the above code-example should still work.